# Modified Gambler's Ruins: going all in in each toss and allowing ties with probability $1-p-q$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, gambling

Consider a modified gambler's ruin problem where in each coin toss the player either wins one more coin with probability $p$ or lose all his coins with probability $1-p$.

a) Give an equation $P_m$ of winning starting with $m$ coins where $0<m<N$ with the law of total probability. Note boundary conditions.

b) Write an expression of probability $P_m$ in terms of $p$.

Consider another version of the gambler's ruin where the player has probability p of winning 1 coin, probability

c)Show that $P_m$ has the same probability as the usual unbalanced gambler ruin with a probability of winning a coin being $\tilde{p}=\frac{p}{p+q}$

So for a), I conditioned on winning the first toss. Suppose $P_m$ is the event of winning starting with $m$ coins. With the law of total probability, $P(P_m)=P(P_m|W)P(W)+P(P_m|W^C)P(W^C)$

Then in b) I substituted in $P(W)=p$, since it is not possible to win without winning the first toss, then $$P(P_m)=P(P_m|W)P(W)$$ $$=pP(P_m|W)$$
$$=p\frac{P(P_m \cap W)}{P(W)}$$
$$=p\frac{P(P_m \cap W)}{P(W)}$$
$$=p\frac{P(W|P_m)P(P_m)}{P(W)}$$
$$=p\frac{p^m}{p}$$
$$=p^m$$

I am not sure if the above logic is correct or how to go about solving the second modified (win one, lose one, staying put) version of the problem? Should I use conditioning as I did or trying to account for the next/previous toss like in the original gambler's ruin problem? i.e. $pP_i + qP_i = pP_{i+1} + qP_{i−1}$

Comment: I am not sure I read $P_m$ being used in the question as an event but instead as the probability of eventually reaching $N$ when starting at $m$, and intuitively $P_m = p P_{m+1}$ so $P_m=p^{N-m}$

Comment: I think I realized that $(|)$ should be $p^{N-m}$. But I am not sure if using conditional probability is the correct approach. Can you explain how you get $p^{N-m}$ from $_=_+1$?

Comment: You can use induction, but intuitively  $P_N=1$ and so $P_{N-1}=p$ and $P_{N-2}=p^2$ and so on down to $P_1=p^{N-1}$, though $P_0=0$